# How to run docker-compose commands with ansible?

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, ansible

In ansible playbook I need to run docker-compose commands. How can I do it? I need to run command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`

Comment: [Check this module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html) for the details.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Updated answer 02/2024:

[`docker_compose_v2`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_v2_module.html) is out since [`community.docker`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/community/docker/) v3.6.0.

You can copy `docker-compose.yml` and run Compose such as:

```yaml
- name: copy Docker Compose files
  copy:
    src: files/{{ item }}
    dest: /somewhere/yourproject/{{ item }}
  loop:
  - docker-compose.yml
  - docker-compose.prod.yml

# use files parameter to use multiple docker-compose.yml files
# mind the _v2 suffix
- name: deploy Docker Compose stack
  community.docker.docker_compose_v2:
    project_src: /somewhere/yourproject
    files:
    - docker-compose.yml
    - docker-compose.prod.yml
```

---

Old answer (06/2020) using `docker_compose` module, only compatible with `docker-compose` < 2.0.0:

You should copy your Docker Compose files and use [`docker_compose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_module.html) module such as:

```yaml
- name: copy Docker Compose files
  copy:
    src: files/{{ item }}
    dest: /somewhere/yourproject/{{ item }}
  loop:
  - docker-compose.yml
  - docker-compose.prod.yml

# use files parameter to use multiple docker-compose.yml files
- name: deploy Docker Compose stack
  community.docker.docker_compose:
    project_src: /somewhere/yourproject
    files:
    - docker-compose.yml
    - docker-compose.prod.yml
```

Edit 2023-08-22: as of today Compose v2 is not supported by Ansible, it only works with v1. There's ongoing work towards [`docker_compose_v2` module](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/pull/586) but it's not available yet. In the meantime you can use `shell` as per [@Tatiana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62453786/5465973)

Comment: Oh, I see that to use docker_compose I need to install a lot of dependencies. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: relies on unmaintained / problematic docker-py currently

Comment: You mean old `community.general.docker_compose`? Just update to use recent `community.docker.docker_compose`

Comment: You're maybe confusing Ansible Docker collection currently at version `3.3.1` (https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/docker?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH7YAAW) and Docker Compose specs currently at `3.8` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/). Ansible Docker collection (packaging compose module) version is not correlated to Docker Compose itself, and is perfectly able to run latest Docker Compose specs and binaries as of time of writing this comment :) (just tested to make sure)

Comment: It sounds like community.docker collection only works with the old EOL docker compose 1.x https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/issues/216

Comment: Indeed, from the issue you linked this MR is mentioned which seems to add `docker_compose_v2` https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/pull/586. I updated answer accordingly regarding Compose v1 and will update again if a v2 module make it's way to main

Answer (score 16):

At the end I decided to use to use shell module. I think @pierre-b answer is more correct but anyway:

```
- name: Run container
  become: True
  shell:
    cmd: "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d"
    chdir: /mydir/
```

Comment: You should definitely avoid using shell when there is a module doing the job for you. Now you also have to manage idempotency (which is done automatically by the module).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also valid but as @Zeitounator pointed it's better to use an Ansible module where possible and avoid using shell commands. Why did the module did not suit you?

Comment: Too many requirements for the module. But probably I will use it in next time, it looks cool.

Comment: "Definitely" - not at all. The module relies on docker-py which is unmaintained and outdated. Don't use modules that don't keep pace / have good community support unless you're ok with staying behind in compatibility and having to rewrite later. Ansible community will eventually figure it out though.

Comment: If I install docker-compose-plugin, or a docker-compose for my flavour of server, I do not see why I should not use this, as it is the simplest and gets the job done.

Comment: @aehlke, thanks for pointing this out. Apparently, the module only supports docker-compose 1x only, [here's the link](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/issues/676#issuecomment-1656146970)